# I'm having a css display issue:

Tags: css

I tried the following code and it is still not working properly....

```
#girlfriend { visibility:hidden } // also tried..
#girlfriend { display:none }
```

but she's still here!

Comment: a CSS class starts with a `.`!

Comment: Use Jquery and remove it `$("#girlfriend").remove();` . Making girfriend hidden is not a good skill for man.

Comment: Did you use firebug/inspector to check the element? 
There's a chance another selector is messing with your #girlfriend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css selector is wrong.

If you refer class name you have to use `.girlfriend`

Or refer to element id `#girlfriend`

Comment: oh true it's actually an id I used, I wrote it wrong - should've been "#girlfriend", the problem remains however :(

Answer (score 1):

have you definetly got a line toi you css file?

`<link rel="Stylesheet" href="my css.css" />`

Check that the css file is being found using firebug or element inspector(Chrome) or whatever IE uses (f12 or something can't remember).

Answer (score 1):

To use as Id use

```
#girlfriend { display:none }
```

To use as class use

```
.girlfriend { display:none }
```

Now apply to an element if you are using class like

```
<div class="girlfriend">My girlfriend</div> <!--For .girlfriend { display:none }-->
```

Or if you are using id then use

```
<div id="girlfriend">My girlfriend</div> <!--For #girlfriend { display:none }-->
```